# NodeJS - How to make TCP server on port 20491 NOT answer http request?

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP server that receives messages from GPS devices via socket connection:

```
var net = require('net');

var PORT = 20491;

var server = net.createServer(function (socket){
    socket.on('data',function(data){
        var received = new Buffer(data);
        console.log("Received: "+received.toString('hex'));
    });
});

server.listen(PORT);
console.log("Server Address(): "+JSON.stringify(server.address()));
```

Let's say that my server is `myserver.mydomain.com`. If I open it on a web browser, the server will receive the message sent by the browser `GET / [...]` even though I only want to receive messages on the port `20491` and not `80` or `8080`

How can I NOT receive (block?) incoming messages that do not come on desired port?

EDIT: This idea came to my mind: Can I somehow block a certain URL of being accessed on this Jelastic+NodeJS+OPENSHIFT server? I could not find any apache or nginx conf files, so I don't know how the configuration file works...

Comment: Yes, the server receives messages from my GPS devices correctly, but if I access `myserver.mydomain.com` from the browser (which I suppose is the same as `myserver.mydomain.com:80`), the server ALSO receives that unwanted http request... Is there a way I could filter that? I tried `server.listen(PORT,HOST)` with host being any possible value: `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` or `<the public IP>` or `<the local IP>` or `<the domain>` and the only thing that works on creating the server is `0.0.0.0` which I believe is what is being used when I omit that.

Comment: When you say "the server receives messages", by "the server" do you mean your program? Or the physical machine?

Comment: I mean my program, that is my `server.js` file. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

In any case the request is coming to your physical system before it is getting handled by your application.

At the system level,You can try implementing a firewall to prevent such requests.

Comment: Suppose I tell you I am using Jelastic+NodeJS infrastructure... and that this Jelastic implementation uses, somehow, the `OPENSHIFT NODE CARTRIDGE`. Do you have any idea what I could do ?

Comment: Hope this would help-https://forums.openshift.com/disable-port-80-and-only-allow-port-443